# Most effective way to calculate Edit distance between two lists?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have two files one is CSV and other one is a text file. Both of them contains Unicode words. My task is to compare words from these two files to correct spelling mistakes.(CSV file contains miss spelled words and text file contains correct words) CSV file contains around 1000 words and text file contains 5000 words.
I have Implemented following code for this task and since I'm new to python it is very inefficient. What are the suggestion to make it more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
 
df = pd.read_csv('C:/mis_spel.csv',encoding='utf8')
list_check_words = df['words'].tolist()

df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/words.txt',encoding='utf8',delimiter='\t')
list_words = df2['word'].tolist()
 
for word in list_check_words:
    for dix in list_words:
        ed = nltk.edit_distance(word, dix)
        if (ed<2):
            print(word, dix, ed)
```

Comment: you could add few works as examples in `df`, `df2` and theh we could run it to test ideas.

Comment: I don't know if will be faster (but it would need much more memory) but you could create DataFrame with cartesian product of words from both dataframes and then you could works with one dataframe instead of two lists - and you could use `df.apply(nltk.edit_distance)`. Because `dataframe` use C/C++ code so it could works faster.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an overkill for your use-case, but still I'm putting it here anyways. AFAIK, these days the industry standard for spelling auto-correction involves looking at the problem through the lens of word embeddings. In older times, an n-gram based probabilistic approach was being used, but not any more.

What you'd want to do, is probably something like the following:

1. Train a model to produce character-level word embeddings
2. Project the entire dictionary to your vector space and build an index for efficient search
3. For each misspelled word, pair it with its nearest neighbor.

I'm adding reference to two different articles below, which explain this in much greater detail. One suggestion though, please try exploring [ANNOY](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_annoy.html) indexing from gensim, it's crazy fast for approx nearest neighbors search. Speaking from personal experience.

- article 1: [Embedding for spelling correction](https://towardsdatascience.com/embedding-for-spelling-correction-92c93f835d79)
- article 2: [Spelling Correction Using Deep Learning: How Bi-Directional LSTM with Attention Flow works in Spelling Correction](https://medium.com/@BhashkarKunal/spelling-correction-using-deep-learning-how-bi-directional-lstm-with-attention-flow-works-in-366fabcc7a2f)

Comment: This is a small part of a bigger problem so word embedding and deep leaning seems too complex. I will look into indexing. Thanks.